# Running Sipp test case multiple times with logging

Tags: automated-tests, sip, autoit

I am using SIPP as a client to test my SIP Server. To test Stability of the server, I would like to run a specific test case for 1000 times. To do this I use AutoIT (this is the usual automation software we use for other clients, and to maintain uniformity, we want to use AutoIt itself).

The thing is I noticed that, after around 100 times running, the response time increases from the server. In AutoIt, I run the test case, and assume that within a minute, the entire test case will be run, and then run the test again(next iteration).

Is there any way, where I can get to know in AutoIt, no reply has come, or an unexpected reply has come, and I can store it.

For example: If simple test case is-> Register--> and Reply is 200 Ok.
if reply 200 ok came ->write to file: Test case iteration number: Successful
if reply 408 timeout came->write to file: test case iteration number: Timeout error
if no reply comes, after certain time out period: test case iteration number: No response error.

Through AutoIt, the way I can think of is by reading file, check for the particular call id, what response came and so on.

I would like to know, if sipp already gives a provision for this?

Comment: I don't know anything about autoit, but sipp has various logging capabilities, include `-trace_err`, which logs unexpected messages. All of the trace options produce one file per run of sipp.

Comment: You are automating an external tool and you want to get the return code? I don't get it. Sorry :-)

Comment: @Xenobiologist I prefer using AutoIt, but if you have a solution which can be done without AutoIT, I dont mind :)

Comment: First of all, what are you really doing? Do you have a piece of code? Please write it in prosa text or something like that. Are you checking whether a server is still alive?